# Is there a reason not to use AssertionHelper with NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I've been using NUnit for a while now, and I have been deriving my test classes from `AssertionHelper`.  By doing that, my tests use a syntax like:

```
Expect(myValue, Is.EqualTo(3), "value wasn't equal to 3");
```

instead of:

```
Assert.That(myValue, Is.EqualTo(3), "value wasn't equal to 3");
```

Almost every example with NUnit that I see uses `Assert.That()` syntax, but it seems that `Expect()` makes more sense (at least to me) as I am expecting a certain behavior from my code.

Is there any downside to using `AssertionHelper` with NUnit, or is it really come down to just a matter of taste/style?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both doing the same and both allows you specifying a custom constraint which implements `IConstraint` interface. From my point of view `Assert()` a little bit lightweight since does not obligate you inheriting all test fixtures from a special class.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with `AssertionHelper` is that very few people use it, so new NUnit features and constraints tend not to get added to it. Because it is neglected and not widely used, the [NUnit team is considering removing it](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1212) or making it a separate package.

The team is looking for feedback from the community on whether or not to remove it, so feel free to comment on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way I name my variables, my tests often end with the line:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
```

which IMO reads better (more fluent) than

```
Expect(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob Prouse is correct that the NUnit team is deprecating AssertionHelper. I had been using it for about 8 months when I found it was obsoleted in an update and I offered to maintain it. The discussion around that was going really slowly and I was a little impatient, so I wrote [NUnit.StaticExpect](https://github.com/fluffynuts/NUnit.StaticExpect) which is on Nuget and offers a drop-in replacement for AssertionHelper, with a "using static" import in your code. I switched a production project over to it and it's working well.

I also started around that time on a different path: [NExpect](https://github.com/fluffynuts/NExpect) which offers a syntax more reminiscent of [Chai](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect) but with extensibility more similar to [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/). NExpect is in a pretty usable state -- I've been using it in my own projects for a while now. There's a [demo project](https://github.com/fluffynuts/NExpect.Demo) which you can use to observe the evolution of assertions through:

1. Assert.{specific method} (eg Assert.AreEqual)
2. Assert.That({value or lambda}, {current-tense constraint})
3. AssertionHelper usage
4. NUnit.StaticExpect usage
5. NExpect usage

As well as giving an example of the extensibility of NExpect. Hope this helps.